# Adding hasMany items to a post ember not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to create a new post and I want to add some tags to that post when I create it.

So let's say I have a list of tag objects in an array.

The `hasMany` tags relationship is an async one by the way.

Here is my code

```
        var post = store.createRecord('post', {
            name: this.get('name'),
            slug: this.get('slug'),
            description: this.get('description'),
        });

        post.get('tags').then(function(post) {
            post.pushObjects(this.get('selectedTags'));
        });

        post.save().then(...);
```

But in the `POST` request the data that's being sent has `tags` as a blank array like `tags:[]`

The tags already exist in the `selectedTags` variable in the controller. These tags are coming straight from the server.

So I have no clue why this is not working.

If anyone has an idea, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `post.get('tags')` is an async call, so it will happen after the `save` in the stated scenario and should be changed to something like this:

```
    var self = this;

    post.get('tags').then(function(tags) {
        tags.pushObjects(self.get('selectedTags'));
        post.save().then(...);
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean that it will happen after the `save`? Does this mean that I need to first `save` the post and then try to add the tags. In which case, why?

Comment: Also I don't want to push objects to `post` I want to push them to `tags`. Unless this is just a typo and you meant `tags`.

Comment: the function passed into the then will execute asynchronously, meaning it could be executed in 1 ms, or 5 years.  Regardless, if you want to save after you've attached the tags you'd want to make sure it happened after the tags were attached.

Comment: What about if the hasMany relationship has attributes, how should those be sent?

Comment: what do you mean by attributes, records?

Comment: in my pivot table I have something like lets say post_id, tag_id, tag_type. So for each tag that's added, it has a specific type. How can I send that information with my tag_ids?